# Google API Service account keys

Tags: google-api, nlp, google-developer-tools

Im trying to get a service account key (service account key) for the google natural language API, the problem is that im creating the key on my ipad and it says the key json file has been downloaded to my laptop. Is there a way to get access to this json file on my ipad?

Comment: The issue is that it said it saved the file on my computer, but i am in my ipad. Where in my ipad could it have of saved it? It seems unlikely that it would have downloaded somewhere in my ipad. Would I have to create the service account key on a computer then send it over to my iPad?

Comment: Check your settings on your browser, where are the files being downloaded. If you are in the same LAN you can shared the file or the download folder to get access to it from your Ipad.

Comment: I din think im explaining this clearly. Im doing all of this  on my ipad. So its impossible that the file is being downloaded on my laptop. You cant download anything from a webpage on an iPad.

Comment: You can't use Service Account Keys with a browser(-based app). What are you trying to do with the Natural Language API from the browser?